# Context separation in microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

I work in a small company and we are about to delve into the Microservices world. As expected, we are hitting a few bumps.

As of now, we are working on a new software to manage heavy machinery, but let us focus on a small bounded context: work order. For the sake of simplicity, I will omit the unnecessary details. Anyway, this bounded context is composed of a technician, a team and the actual work order. A team is composed of a group of technicians and a team manager, which is also a technician. Let us think about one little aspect of the software: a technician should be able to see all the work orders issued to them and, if they happen to be the manager of a team, they should be able to see all the work orders issued to any members of that team.

My first idea was to create a single service. Upon some research, I started to wonder if I should create two services: one to manage the teams and technicians and one to actually manage the work orders. The problem with the second approach is that part of the logic that controls which orders should be retrieved will have to be placed inside the API Gateway / BFF. As the work orders have no knowledge of teams (which I actually think it is the correct design), the API Gateway would have to retrieve the teams in which the technician is the manager in order to retrieve all the work orders for all members of those teams.

My concern here is that it seem some business logic is leaking to the API Gateway and I am not sure that is all right, I am also afraid of creating anemic microservices. On the other hand, this bounded context might be used on a different software, which may not make use of the concept of teams.

I also thought about creating a third service to coordinate this work but have not found any reasons to support the idea as of now.

So, to summarize: should I create one, two or three services? I am bound to creating two, but cannot seem to decide just yet.

Thanks for the heads up guys.

Comment: do you have already a working monolith?

Comment: Hey Constantin, thanks for the comment. To answer your question, I do not. This is a brand new software and this context, in specific, will probably be used in another software, which is also yet to be developed.

Comment: it is recommended to not start with microservices, but with a monolith

Comment: make first a working, **modular** monolith and only then refactor to microservices

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html

Comment: Constatin, thanks again for taking your time in helping us. I understand your point, sadly, some things are beyond our control and I am afraid developing a monolith first will not be possible. What is funny about the text is that one of the subjects it addresses is about the difficulty in getting the correct boundaries. Anyway, thanks again man!

Comment: What value are you expecting to reap from your microservice architecture?   I think the answer to this question will help illuminate what your services should look like.   For example, if you want to meet elastic demands, you need your instances to be relatively independent.  If they have a common, lengthy bottleneck, you won’t reap benefit from multiple instances.   The quandary is that avoiding the synchronization (bottleneck) often lowers the per-instance performance.  Thus the balance is between best and worst case performance.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is really difficult to answer because API gateways could be domain specific which means you can have a little business logic in them or it could be as generic as possible. Rather than completely a technical problem, its more of a product problem and depends how you would be evolving this architecture and where it plays in the larger ecosystem of services that you may have.

Comment: I must thank you all for taking your time to give us some insight. I think we'll approach this as a single service for the time being. Rather than trying to cut the services into tables / entities, we are better suited taking into account how closely the parts communicate. It may seem obvious but I have seen my share of examples in which the services represent a database hierarchy, some for being oversimplified, other not so much.
I’m sure this problem will still haunt us though. For that, we have yet to decide in creating a CQRS like service or migrating a bit of logic to the gateway.